# Mongoose: Score query then sort by score - non text fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my db, I have a collection of books. 
Each have:

- a count of upvotes
- a count of downvotes
- a count of views

I would like to sort my db by scoring as follows:

- upvote: 8 points
- downvote: -4 points
- view: 1/2 point

So the score will be:

```
(NumberOfViews*(1/2)) + (NumberOfDownvotes*-4)+ (NumberOfUpvotes*8)
```

So if I have:

```
book1 = {name:'book1', views:3000,upvotes:340, downvotes:120}
book2 = {name:'book2', views:9000,upvotes:210, downvotes:620}
book3 = {name:'book3', views:7000,upvotes:6010, downvotes:2}
```

The score should be:

```
book1Score = 3740
book2Score = 3700
book3Score = 51572
```

And the query should output

```
book3,book1,book2
```

How can I achieve such a thing in mongoose?

**Bonus:** What if I want records that are more recent to rank higher than older records on that same query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well I ended up doing it all inside mongoose.

I run this query every 24 hours to re-score my collection.

```
Book.aggregate(
    [
        //I match my query  
        {$match:query},
        {
            $project: {
                //take the id for reference
                _id: 1,
                //calculate the score of the views
                viewScore: {
                    $multiply: [ "$views", 0.5 ]
                },
                //calculate the score of the upvotes
                upvoteScore: {
                    $multiply: [ {$size: '$upvotes'}, 8 ]
                },
                //calculate the score of the downvotes
                downvoteScore: {
                    $multiply: [ {$size: '$downvotes'}, -4 ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            //project a second time
            $project: {
               //take my id for reference
                _id: 1,
               //get my total score
                score: {
                    $add:['$viewScore','$upvoteScore','$downvoteScore']
                },
            }
        },
        //sort by the score.
        {$sort : {'score' : -1}},
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to query mongoose for the list of book then do the sorting yourself.

Something like:

```
// Get query results from mongoose then ...

books.sort((a,b) => {
  return ((a.views*(1/2))+(a.downvotes*-4)+(a.upvotes*8))-((b.view*(1/2))+ b.downvotes*-4)+(b.upvotes*8))
});
```

This would sort the books in ascending order of highest points

**EDIT**: The above answer is for sorting after you've received the query. (And also just realized you want descending for above^ so just switch the placement to be `b - a`)

If you want to receive the query already sorted, you could instead calculate the score at the time you input the `book` and add that as a field. The use mongoose's Query#sort. Which would look something like

```
query.sort({ score: 'desc'});
```

More info on Query#sort: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: Thanks! This seems like exactly what I'm after! Can you please explain how the function works? what are a and b?

Comment: Wait, that means I have to store the entire query result in my server's RAM? That won't work...

Comment: The first answer is a higher order function for sorting an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort. And I edited the answer for if you want mongoose to sort